# What is the Difference

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts, struts-1, struts-tags

i want to know the differences of these statements in Struts 1.x version..

```
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%> and

<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
```

explain what happen internally

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Basically on is [File URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) and other a [URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme).

They are basically used for resolution of tag values
http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/HTTP-URI2.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>
```

This gives the absolute path to the .tld file. Which in this case is inside /WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
```

This doesn't deal with an absolute path. If using this type of uri, need to specify in the web.xml, where the .tld file for this uri resides in.

```
<taglib>
  <taglib-uri>
    http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean
  </taglib-uri>
  <taglib-location>
    /struts-bean.tld
  </taglib-location>
</taglib>
```